# d3js: How to make the bubble chart zoomable?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

Currently I have a bubble chart made using d3js which is as shown [image]

I have a lot of data to be plotted on the map(Currently I am showing only some bubbles). Is there any way I can make the graph focusable? I want to give the user a funcionality where he can zoom on certain area.

How do I do that in d3js?

The script that I have is as follows:

```
var data = [{name: "A", rank: 0, student_percentile: 100.0, 
         admit_probability: 24},
        {name: "B", rank: 45, student_percentile: 40.3, 
         admit_probability: 24},
        {name: "C", rank: 89, student_percentile: 89.7, 
         admit_probability: 24},
        {name: "D", rank: 23, student_percentile: 10.9, 
         admit_probability: 24},
        {name: "E", rank: 56, student_percentile: 30.3, 
         admit_probability: 24}];

var margin = 40,
    width = 600,
    height = 400;
function d3(data){
    //var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50}

    console.log(data);
    //d3.extent(data, function(d) { return +d.admit_probability; })

    xscale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain(
                d3.extent(data, function(d) { return +d.student_percentile; })
            )
        .nice() 
        .range([0, width]);

    yscale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return +d.rank; }))
        .nice()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(xscale);

    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(yscale);

    svg = d3.select('.chart')
        .classed("svg-container", true)
        .append('svg')
        .attr('class', 'chart')
        .attr("viewBox", "0 0 680 490")
        .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
        .classed("svg-content-responsive", true)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin + "," + margin + ")");

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

    var local = d3.local();
    circles = svg.selectAll(null)
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append("circle")
          .attr("cx", width / 2)
          .attr("cy", height / 2)
          .attr("opacity", 0.3)
          .attr("r", 20)
          .style("fill", function(d){
            if(+d.admit_probability <= 40){
                return "red";
            }
            else if(+d.admit_probability > 40 && +d.admit_probability <= 70){
                return "yellow";
            }
            else{
                return "green";
            }
          })
          .attr("cx", function(d) {
            return xscale(+d.student_percentile);
          })
          .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return yscale(+d.rank);
          })
          .on('mouseover', function(d, i) {
            local.set(this, d3.select(this).style("fill"));
            d3.select(this)
              .transition()
              .duration(1000)
              .ease(d3.easeBounce)
              .attr("r", 32)
              .style("cursor", "pointer")
              .attr("text-anchor", "middle");
            }
           )
          .on('mouseout', function(d, i) {
            d3.select(this).style("fill", local.get(this));
            d3.select(this).transition()
              .style("opacity", 0.3)
              .attr("r", 20)
              .style("cursor", "default")
            .transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .ease(d3.easeBounce)
          });

    texts = svg.selectAll(null)
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('text')
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return xscale(+d.student_percentile);
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return yscale(+d.rank);
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return +d.admit_probability;
      })
      .attr("pointer-events", "none")
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", "12px")
      .attr("fill", "red");

    svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + " ," + (height + margin) + ")")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Percentile");

    svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 0 - margin)
        .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
        .attr("dy", "1em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Rank");

    $('circle').tipsy({ 
        gravity: 'w', 
        html: true, 
        title: function() {
            var d = this.__data__;
            return d.name + '<br/> Rank: ' + d.rank; 
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: share a editable fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/h87403om/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add simple zoom in/out functionality using d3's zoom event handler and transform the chart dimensions.

```
svg = d3.select('.chart')
    .classed("svg-container", true)
    .append('svg')
    .attr('class', 'chart')
    .attr("viewBox", "0 0 680 490")
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
    .classed("svg-content-responsive", true)
    // call d3 Zoom
    .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
        svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
        }))
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin + "," + margin + ")");
```

To Zoom in/out the user can either use mouse scroll or double-click to zoom in and shift+double-click to zoom out.

An alternative approach is to use d3js brush function to select an area and zoom in/out

```
    var brush = d3.brush().extent([[0, 0], [width, height]]).on("end", brushended),
        idleTimeout,
        idleDelay = 350;

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "brush")
        .call(brush);

    function brushended() {
        var s = d3.event.selection;
        if (!s) {
            if (!idleTimeout) return idleTimeout = setTimeout(idled, idleDelay);

            yscale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return +d.rank; })).nice();

            xscale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return +d.student_percentile; })).nice()

        } else {

            xscale.domain([s[0][0], s[1][0]].map(xscale.invert, xscale));
            yscale.domain([s[1][1], s[0][1]].map(yscale.invert, yscale));
            svg.select(".brush").call(brush.move, null);
        }
        zoom();
    }

    function idled() {
        idleTimeout = null;
    }

    function zoom() {

        var t = svg.transition().duration(750);
        svg.select(".x axis").transition(t).call(xAxis);
        svg.select(".y axis").transition(t).call(yAxis);
        // apply new scale to the svg elements that depend on scale.
        svg.selectAll("text").transition(t)
          .attr("x", function(d) {
            return xscale(+d.student_percentile);
          })
          .attr("y", function(d) {
            return yscale(+d.rank);
          })
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I had tried doing this after some more research but once user double clicks on the page, it gets zoomed in but without refreshing the page, there is no way to go back to inital state. I tried some tutorials also, but all of them had this issue. Basically, what is the procedure to zoom-out?

Comment: @Yesha the most user-friendly way is to zoom in/out using mouse scroll. The other action to achieve the same is to double-click to zoom in and shit+double-click to zoom out. Because this is not intuitive interaction, I will update my answer to use d3js brush functionality.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am able to use your first solution but really sorry to say I am not able to understand how to use the second one. I called the methods you have given with my current svg element. After that, what do you mean by "select an area and zoom in/out". I am using a web-interface. So, I am not able to understand what I should do to test it? Also, our web-site is mobile responsive, so I'll be using the same functionality on mobile.

Comment: please refer to this example for understanding second method. https://bl.ocks.org/EfratVil/d956f19f2e56a05c31fb6583beccfda7